# conditional find and replace with sed

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I have a text file with thousands of bank transaction in it and I need to search and replace text based on text found on another line of the transaction. Each transaction is listed as such...

```
2016/01/08 * POS DEBIT LOWES #02793* SPOKANE VALLE WA #7522
    Expenses:Unknown                         $289.78
    Assets:INB Checking
```

I need to be able to search the top line for 'LOWES' and if text matches it will change the expenses column to Expenses:Building Materials

So the whole transaction would like like this...

```
2016/01/08 * POS DEBIT LOWES #02793* SPOKANE VALLE WA #7522
    Expenses:Building Materials              $289.78
    Assets:INB Checking
```

I know that I can use sed to do find and replace but how can I do so based of a pattern match on the top line?

Comment: it will be better if you show how these transactions are separated, for ex with newlines in between? `awk` is better suited, but I think for your purpose, using `N` command would do...

Comment: There are no lines in between the transactions, they just continue as shown without any separation.

Comment: hmm ok.. I think using sed's `n` or `N` command would fit here.. see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51 for an example

Comment: what is your *the top line*? the most recent or the first line in the file with `LOWES` keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a starting address and loop with the `t` command to find and replace your pattern up to next line not starting with numbers:

```
sed '/LOWES/{:a;N;/\n[^0-9]/{s/\(Expenses:\).*/\1Building Materials/;P;D;}}' file
```

Try the `-i` flag to edit the file *in place*:

```
sed -i '/LOWES/{:a;N;/\n[^0-9]/{s/\(Expenses:\).*/\1Building Materials/;P;D;}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that every LOWES expense starts with a line matching LOWES and ends with a line matching Expenses, you can just do this:

`sed -e '/LOWES/,/Expenses/s/Unknown/Building Materials/'`

This says that in every range of lines from /LOWES/ to /Expenses/ replace 'Unknown' with 'Building Materials'.

If you use a simpler pattern like this instead of the more robust solution suggested by SLePort, it's essential that you diff the results and ensure you didn't mangle something else.